# Predicate logic : translate Everyone knows some hard-working people

Tags: predicate-logic, logic-translation

I am stuck with my course work as an undergraduate. It says to write the following statement in the form of predicate logic. The statement is "e.   Everyone knows some hard-working people." The one I wrote is 
"$∀x \space ∃y(People(x) ∧ People(y) ∧ (Hardworking(y) ∧Knows(x, y)))$"
Is this correct??

Comment: Your symbols aren't showing up for me. Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: What is x? And what is People(x)?

Comment: That's what I wrote and I think it is wrong. Can you tell me the write answer?

Answer (score 1):

With these questions, there could potentially be a lot of correct answers, depending on how you define your variables.

One solution is to denote $P$ as the set of all people. Then we want to write something like "for any person x, there's another person y that is hardworking and that is known by x." Writing this in the mathematical logic notation, we would get $\forall x \in P, \exists y \in P  \ni (Hardworking(y) \wedge Knows(x,y))$.